# Codewars strip comments problem randomly working/not-working for 'attempt' tests

Tags: python

I am currently on the 4kyu problem on Codewars, where given a string and a list of characters, your function is supposed to remove the characters in the string and any other characters that follow, up to the end of the line. I came up with a solution that I think should work. Since I need to remove every character in the string after the special character is found, I split the string by '\n' since that marks the end of the line.
Then I proceeded to write the function that checks all the substrings:

```
def solution(string,markers):
  str_arr = string.split('\n')
  print(str_arr)
  new_str = []

  for substring in str_arr:
    count = 0
    for mark in markers:
        if mark in substring:
            count +=1
    if count == 0:
        new_str.append(substring)
    for char in substring:
        if char in markers:
            sbstr = substring[:substring.index(char)-1]
            new_str.append(sbstr.strip())
            if str_arr.index(substring) == len(str_arr)-1:
                break
            print(new_str)

    solution = '\n'.join(new_str)
    return solution
```

I first check if the substring even has the marker in it and if not, I add it to the new list. This solution works for most of the tests provided by Codewars, but for some reason, there are tests which this function just won't solve. One of them is:

Testing for solution("! apples bananas bananas apples -\nwatermelons '\npears cherries oranges ^ apples\ncherries watermelons strawberries bananas strawberries", ['@', ',', '=', '-', "'", '!'])

, where my output is:

It should work with random inputs too: '! apples bananas bananas apples\n! apples bananas bananas apples\nwatermelons\npears cherries oranges ^ apples\ncherries watermelons strawberries bananas strawberries' should equal '\nwatermelons\npears cherries oranges ^ apples\ncherries watermelons strawberries bananas strawberries'

Currently, I don't know how to tackle these issues, especially since the function works perfectly well for around 40/48 cases. Thanks for any suggestions on how I could improve my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, you're supposed to remove only the trailing spaces.
Use `rstrip` for that. `strip` will remove whitspaces from both ends.

Next, you should join the final strings.

I'll leave the code for reference:

```py
def solution(string, markers):
    ss = string.split('\n')
    for i in range(len(ss)):
        s = ss[i]
        for marker in markers:
            index = s.find(marker)
            if index >= 0:
                s = s[:index].rstrip()
        ss[i] = s
    return '\n'.join(ss)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand what you're doing in your code, but I thought this was supposed to remove the markers, which it did for the most part, so I don't quite understand why it did work for some cases but not for others:
sbstr = substring[:substring.index(char)-1]
new_str.append(sbstr.rstrip())